# vscode with ubuntu + wsl 2 never prompts for gpg passphrase even after configuration just "failed to write commit data"

Tags: visual-studio-code, windows-subsystem-for-linux, gnupg, vscode-remote, wsl-2

I'm trying to get vscode to prompt for passphrase when trying to commit as it does in windows OR at least make the time between having to enter the passphrase a lot longer.

I'm using latest on ubuntu + WSL 2, both installed today.

GPG works in the CLI if I run a test as follows:

```
echo "test" | gpg --clearsign
```

I'm being prompted for a passphrase and all is well. Then I'd be able to sign commits in vscode temporarily.

Is there an option to make the time between entering the passphrase a lot longer at least as a workaround?

EDIT:

I also have to enter this everytime I reboot my computer:

```
export GPG_TTY=$(tty)
```

Otherwise the above workaround won't work. It's been insane trying to fix this, probably spent at least 1 full day but to no use.

Answer (score 1):

In your `~/.gnupg/gpg-agent.conf` [file](https://www.gnupg.org/documentation/manuals/gnupg/Agent-Options.html), add the following:

```
default-cache-ttl 28800
max-cache-ttl 28800
```

You can also add the following to your `~/.bashrc` so you do not have to manually enter it each time:

```
export GPG_TTY=$TTY
echo "test" | gpg --clearsign > /dev/null 2>&1
```

This prompts me for my password once on start and should cache for 8 hours. The `> /dev/null 2>&1` bit hides the output. Currently, this is the workaround I am using--which is not ideal but bearable.

Comment: Also, as stated [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/608921/296430), it its more reliable to use `export GPG_TTY=$TTY` command instead.

Comment: Thank you, I made the update based on your suggestion.